# Convert multi pages PDF into single html file using pdftohtml poppler utility

Tags: poppler, pdf-parsing, pdf-to-html

I am converting PDF document into HTML using poppler utility. But its creating separate html file for each page, but I want a single HTML file after converting pdf to html.

I used following syntax:

```
pdftohtml -c abc.pdf
```

But its creating abc-1.html, abc-2.html, .... etc

I also tried with  `pdftohtml -c abc.pdf abc.html` but not getting expecting output.

Can anyone tell how to get a html output in single file instead of multiple html files?

Answer (score 5):

I have achieved this with -s option

For example:

```
pdftohtml -c -s -noframes abc.pdf abc.html
```

Comment: @ Deepti Kakade :its working fine for me but i am getting an issue. its creating ALL PAGE WITH LEFT ALIGNMENT. IT SHOULD BE SAME THAT WAS IN PDF.  Do you have any idea how can i do ?

Comment: I have to say a BIG Thank you, I totally missed the '-noframes' flag :-)

Answer (score 0):

The question is old but needs to be supplemented with information

The solution with pdftohtml works but loses the formatting

Preserves formatting is **pdf2htmlEX**

On new builds of Linux, this package is not present and deb packages are not installed

[Only works through docker](https://github.com/RonyMacfly/pdf2htmlEX)

```
sudo docker pull bwits/pdf2htmlex

sudo docker run -ti --rm -v /home/user/Documents/pdfToHtml:/pdf bwits/pdf2htmlex pdf2htmlEX --zoom 1.3 file.pdf
```